# copy to clipboard doesn't worked for hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created table cell with copy text.. when I click copy it gets the value of particular ipno cell and post it to the input.. then I copy it into clipboard using execCommand.. It is working fine when I make input type as text.. but the problem is that it doesn't copy the value after I make input as hidden.. because I doesn't need to show input..
 my table tr is as follow

```
 <td align="center" ><span class = 'cpy'><?echo $row['ipno'];?></span> <span class="text-primary copytd"> Copy</span> </td>
```

and my input to copy ipno from table is

```
 <input type="hidden" name = "ip" id="divcopy" />
```

and my jQuery and Javascript function to copy on clipboard is

```
 $('.copytd').on("click",function(e) {
  var copyText = $(this).closest('tr').find(".cpy").text();
   // $("#divcopy").val(copyText);
    $('input[name="ip"]').val(copyText);
    var di = $("#divcopy").val();
    myFunction();
  // $(this).closest('tr').find(".copytd").text('Copied');
 });
 function myFunction() {
var copyT = document.getElementById("divcopy");
copyT.select();
copyT.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
document.execCommand("copy");
alert("copied");
}
```

note: it is working fine when I make input as visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy to clipboard with type='hidden'

use 'text'

This is part of my code.
Refer to it

Make and use a 'blind' class to hide it.

```
.blind{visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;
top:0;left:0;width:0;height:0;font-size:0;line-height:0}
```

If you are using it in web, you may not need readonly, and contenteditable property.

Those are for mobile to prevent keypad pop up

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="blind" id="myLink" value="" 
readonly="readonly" contenteditable="true">
```

JS

```
function copyLink(link, title) {
    $('#myLink').val(link);
    var linkUrl = document.getElementById("myLink");
    linkUrl.select();
    linkUrl.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

For your Code

HTML

```
 <input type="text" name = "ip" id="divcopy"  class="blind" value="" readonly="readonly" contenteditable="true">
```

JS

```
$('.copytd').on("click",function(e) {
  var copyText = $(this).closest('tr').find(".cpy").text();
   // $("#divcopy").val(copyText);
    $('input[name="ip"]').val(copyText);
    var di = $("#divcopy").val();
    myFunction();
  // $(this).closest('tr').find(".copytd").text('Copied');
 });
 function myFunction() {
var copyT = document.getElementById("divcopy");
copyT.select();
copyT.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
document.execCommand("copy");
alert("copied");
}
```